# How to sign compiled dll with other pfx file

Tags: c#, dll, compiler-errors

I have a compiled dll that was signed with Certificate A, which is not available any more.
The source code for the dll is also lost, but it is needed in a legacy project (.Net 4.6).

I have changed the certificate in the legacy project, however when i compile:

> Could not load file or assembly 'the dll,Version:0.0.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x90131044)

I found several posts on how to decompile, change the signing and then recompile, however all of them are using `.snk` and not `.pfx`

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to decompile the original DLL using dotPeek and to add the decompiled dll as project to the visual studio solution.
After some cleanup it compiled and i could change the certificate.